# Changing QPushButton Color when Pressed

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Is there a way to change the background color of a QPushButton which is pressed by modifying its QPalette object?  I realize it can be done with style sheets but would like a way to do it by modifying the QPalette.  Something similar to how one changes the background color of the button when not pressed:

```
QPushButton myButton;
QPalette p(myButton.palette());

p.setColor(QPalette::Button, QColor("#ffffff"));
myButton.setPalette(p);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to QPushButton's [pressed()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#pressed) signal and update the palette with your desired color and then connect to [released()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#released) signal and switch back the color to the old color. That should do it.

You may want to run [update()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update-1) after settings the colors or in extreme cases [repaint()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#repaint).

Answer (score 4):

Simply add a stylesheet to the qbushbutton itself or to his parent qwidget:

```
qwidget.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:checked { background-color: red; }")
```

This will set the background color to red when the QPushButton is checked.

Comment: To make this work one has to make the button `checkable` in property.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the button's [pressed](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qabstractbutton.html#pressed) signal and set the palette in the connected slot. You may have to call `repaint()` to force an immediate update.

Answer (score 1):

you can set stylesheet for button when it is pressed.. [here is the Example](http://qt-articles.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-add-stylesheet-for-button-in-qt.html) tells how to set style sheet for button.. but in your case u need to have two different style sheets, one is button pressed and similarly when it is released you should reset with some other stylesheet.