# change color of pushbutton when pushbutton is active

Tags: qt

What is the best way to change to color of the button when pushbutton is active. for example ; pushbutton passive:its color is gray push button active :its color is green

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing QPushButton Color when Pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928411/changing-qpushbutton-color-when-pressed?rq=1) which is for C++ and [QPushButton is not changing the background-color proper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669385/qpushbutton-is-not-changing-the-background-color-proper). This might be different, depending on the language context. Would be great if we could merge all answers into one Q/A page.

Comment: @cfi there are perfect Qt documentation with samples about customizing most widgets. Do you really think that it should be duplicated in stackoverflow? - https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Comment: @Dmitry: I don't understand your comment. My links do not point to Qt docs, but to questions on stackoverflow similar to this one. If your comment is misplaced, and you really wanted to address the example I brought up in my answer: Then, yes, the goal of stackoverflow is to not being forced to go to other websites. While we don't want a copy&paste of existing documentation websites (also incurs license/copyright issues), we do encourage complete answers on this site. If you want to discuss this further I'd encourage you to carry this to Meta.

Answer (score 1):

```
setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: gray; }\n"
              "QPushButton:enabled { background-color: green; }\n");
```

You can apply this method on single button but I recommend to apply it on `QAppliaction` so it will have effect on all `QPushButton`s

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

[Marek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22655668/923794) is elegant. If you need to change more attributes than just the colors, subclass from PushButton and provide the required slot for `pressed`. Here's an example in Python (using PySide) that displays two different texts on the button, depending on whether it is active or not:

```
class TogglePushButtonWidget(QPushButton):
    """Toggles between on and off text

    Changes color when in on state"""
    def __init__(self, parent, on, off):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.on = on
        self.off = off
        self.state = True
        self.rotate_state()
        self.pressed.connect(self.toggle_state)    
    def toggle_state(self):
        self.state = not self.state
        if self.state:
            self.setText(self.on)
            self.connect_w.setStyleSheet('background: #bbffbb;')
        else:
            self.setText(self.off)
            self.connect_w.setStyleSheet('')
```